# Utils for Android Location Manager

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationmanager

I'm looking for a library that would make it easier to use Location Manager in Android. I would like it to support timeout, obtaining location from several location providers and choosing the best estimate out of the obtained results.

Do you guys know any library that offers this functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html
And he posted lots of code if you follow to his blog